# How to change rows to columns by date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv data file in following format, I want to change the rows to columns , but this conversion needs to be done per stock and per date.

```
Ticker,Indicator,Date,Value
STOCK A,ACCRUALS,3/31/2005,-10.44
STOCK A,ACCRUALS,3/31/2006,0.44
STOCK A,AE,3/31/2005,3.97
STOCK A,AE,3/31/2006,3.67
STOCK A,ASETTO,3/31/2005,0.762
STOCK A,ASETTO,3/31/2006,0.9099
```

Output

```
Ticker,Date,ACCRUALS,AE,ASETTO
STOCK A,3/31/2005,-10.44,3.97,0.762
STOCK A,3/31/2006,0.44,3.67,0.9099
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ticker,Indicator,Date,Value
STOCK A,ACCRUALS,3/31/2005,-10.44
STOCK A,ACCRUALS,3/31/2006,0.44
STOCK A,AE,3/31/2005,3.97
STOCK A,AE,3/31/2006,3.67
STOCK A,ASETTO,3/31/2005,0.762
STOCK A,ASETTO,3/31/2006,0.9099
```

Let's just say your data are in a dataframe called `df`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = df.set_index(df['Date'])
>>> for ind in set(df['Indicator']):
...     filtered_df = df[df['Indicator'] == ind]
...     df[ind] = filtered_df['Value']
... 
>>> cols_to_keep = ['Ticker', 'Date'] + list(set(df['Indicator']))
>>> trimmed_df = df[cols_to_keep]
>>> trimmed_df = trimmed_df.drop_duplicates()
>>> trimmed_df
            Ticker       Date  ACCRUALS    AE  ASETTO
Date                                                 
3/31/2005  STOCK A  3/31/2005    -10.44  3.97  0.7620
3/31/2006  STOCK A  3/31/2006      0.44  3.67  0.9099
```

That should take each unique value for `df['Indicator']` and make a new column out of the `df['Value']` column for that particular indicator.

You can use `reset_index()` to set the dataframe's indices back to zero:

```
>>> trimmed_df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

And, instead of using `cols_to_keep`, you can do:

```
>>> trimmed_df.drop("Indicator", axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: df = df.set_index(df['Date']) is giving error raise KeyError("No column(s) named: %s" % str(key[mask]))

Comment: When I changed it to df = df.set_index(['Date']) , it is giving error raise Exception('Index has duplicate keys: %s' % duplicates)
Exception: Index has duplicate keys: ['3/31/2005', '3/31/2006']